# JAXB API to generate Java source files directly to OutputStream

Tags: jaxb

I have a schema file and I want to generate the class files directly into MEMORY instead of file system. I have searched a lot, but everywhere I am finding API to generate java files into filesystem only.

Can any please provide links of API to generate the java source files directly into memory.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't leveraged this code in the way you described, but this fragment might point you in the right direction:

```
import com.sun.codemodel.*;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.*;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.api.*;

SchemaCompiler sc = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
sc.setEntityResolver(new YourEntityResolver());
sc.setErrorListener(new YourErrorListener());
sc.parseSchema(SYSTEM_ID, element);
S2JJAXBModel model = sc.bind();
```

Comment: are we allowed to use com.sun.* code in our production code? Aren't the above package classes subject to change? Please clarify.

Comment: @Harish - There isn't a standard API for generating JAXB source from an XML schema.  You will need to leverage APIs from one of the available schema-to-java tools from a JAXB implementation.  The API above comes from the Metro JAXB implementation.

Comment: @Harish - How are you planning to leverage the source generated directly into memory?

Comment: I will use JavaCompiler in memory compilation feature to generate the classes.

Comment: Could You post more details of the solution? It's very interesting